# Increase space between node label and start of Gantt chart

Tags: spacing, nodes, gantt

I just want to increase the space between the node labels and the start of my gantt chart. It just needs to be enough so that the first one doesn't over lap with the milestone. Any ideas how to do it? I would still like the text to be right aligned.

[image: Gantt]

Edit: Apologies, I should have included my code to produce this chart. Here it is:

```
\begin{ganttchart}[ 
vgrid={{Gray}},
time slot format= {isodate},
x unit = 0.8cm,
y unit title = 0.6cm,
y unit chart = 0.6cm,
compress calendar,
bar label node/.style={text width=6cm,align=right,font=\RaggedLeft, anchor=east},
milestone label node/.style={text width=6cm,align=right,font=\RaggedLeft, anchor=east},
group label node/.style={text width=6cm,align=right,font=\RaggedLeft, anchor=east},
%FlonLon suggstion tried here] 
{2018-12-01}{2019-12-31}
\gantttitlecalendar{year, month=shortname} \\
\ganttmilestone[milestone/.append style={fill=gray!50}]{Proposal decision}{2018-11-30} \\ %0
\ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=red!90}]{Potential proposal amendments}{2018-12-10}{2018-12-21} \\ %1
\ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=red!90}]{Travel \& accommodation research}{2019-01-01}{2019-02-28} \\ %2
\ganttmilestone[milestone/.append style={fill=gray!50}]{Travel \& accommodation booking deadline}{2019-02-28} \\ %3
\ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=orange!90}]{Background theory reading}{2019-03-01}{2019-06-30} \\ %4
\ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=orange!90}]{Final admin (insurance, accounts etc.)}{2019-06-01}{2019-06-30} \\ %5     
\ganttgroup[group/.append style={fill=blue!90}]{\textbf{IPP, Prague}}{2019-07-01}{2019-09-30} \\ %6
\ganttmilestone[milestone/.append style={fill=gray!50}]{Sandpit event}{2019-09-01} \\ %7
\ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=OliveGreen}]{Writing project up}{2019-10-07}{2019-11-31} \\ %8
\ganttlink{elem1}{elem2}
\ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
\ganttlink{elem3}{elem4}
\ganttlink{elem4}{elem6}
\ganttlink{elem5}{elem6}
\ganttlink{elem6}{elem8}
\end{ganttchart}
```

@FlonLon, I have tried your fix but it didn't work. I assume it is because I am also using Compress calendar or declaring other things about the nodes?

Comment: Please provide us with the code that produced that chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would replace `anchor=east` in the label node styles with `left=7pt` (or some other distance, adjust as you see fit).

I could also suggest to define a style for all the common options in the different label node styles. I.e. add

```
\tikzset{
  labelnodes/.style={text width=6cm,align=right,font=\RaggedLeft, left=7pt}
}
```

and then use

```
bar label node/.style={labelnodes},
milestone label node/.style={labelnodes},
group label node/.style={labelnodes},
```

If you have specific options for one of those three, just add it after `labelnodes`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt,ragged2e}
\tikzset{
  labelnodes/.style={text width=6cm,align=right,font=\RaggedLeft, left=7pt}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[ 
vgrid={{Gray}},
time slot format= {isodate},
x unit = 0.8cm,
y unit title = 0.6cm,
y unit chart = 0.6cm,
compress calendar,
bar label node/.style={labelnodes},
milestone label node/.style={labelnodes},
group label node/.style={labelnodes},
] 
{2018-12-01}{2019-12-31}
\gantttitlecalendar{year, month=shortname} \\
\ganttmilestone[milestone/.append style={fill=gray!50}]{Proposal decision}{2018-11-30} \\ %0
\ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=red!90}]{Potential proposal amendments}{2018-12-10}{2018-12-21} \\ %1
\ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=red!90}]{Travel \& accommodation research}{2019-01-01}{2019-02-28} \\ %2
\ganttmilestone[milestone/.append style={fill=gray!50}]{Travel \& accommodation booking deadline}{2019-02-28} \\ %3
\ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=orange!90}]{Background theory reading}{2019-03-01}{2019-06-30} \\ %4
\ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=orange!90}]{Final admin (insurance, accounts etc.)}{2019-06-01}{2019-06-30} \\ %5     
\ganttgroup[group/.append style={fill=blue!90}]{\textbf{IPP, Prague}}{2019-07-01}{2019-09-30} \\ %6
\ganttmilestone[milestone/.append style={fill=gray!50}]{Sandpit event}{2019-09-01} \\ %7
\ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=OliveGreen}]{Writing project up}{2019-10-07}{2019-11-31} \\ %8
\ganttlink{elem1}{elem2}
\ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
\ganttlink{elem3}{elem4}
\ganttlink{elem4}{elem6}
\ganttlink{elem5}{elem6}
\ganttlink{elem6}{elem8}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked for me! I'm not sure if it's just my eyes but it looks like the milestone lables don't line up with the others exactly when using the same #pt on each, but it might just be a tric of the eyes. This worked perfectly, thanks Torbjorn T.

Comment: @StevenThomas Just a trick of the eyes I think. Take my code and add `draw` to the `labelnodes` style, and you'll see that all the nodes line up perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

## 1. MEW Solution

Here is a MWE that solves the problem by adjusting the label format. Documentation used [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[milestone label text={#1~\hspace{1pt}}]{1}{6}
        \gantttitle{2018}{6} \\
        \gantttitlelist{1,...,6}{1} \\
        \ganttmilestone{Milestone}{0}\\
        \ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{2} 
    \end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

The key is `[milestone label text={#1~\hspace{1pt}}]`.

Before:

[image: gantt chart with label overlap]

After:

[image: gantt chart without label overlap]

I would personally adjust the other label types as well so that they have the same distance to the chart, but you get the drift.

## 2. OP-Specific solution

Your code doesn't include your used packages so it took quite a while to get the code to compile at all. The `hspace` option indeed no longer works with your code, instead, I just included `milestone label text={#1\mbox{ }}`. It's not pretty but it does shift your label just left of the milestone.

Here is the code I used:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt,tikz,xcolor,pgfkeys,pgfplots,ragged2e,pgfkeys}
\definecolor{OliveGreen}{RGB}{59,179,0}
\definecolor{Gray}{RGB}{211,211,211}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[ 
    vgrid={{Gray}},
    time slot format=isodate-yearmonth,
    x unit = 0.5cm,
    y unit title = 0.6cm,
    y unit chart = 0.6cm,
    bar label node/.style={text width=6cm,align=right,font=\RaggedLeft, anchor=east},
    milestone label node/.style={text width=6cm,align=right,font=\RaggedLeft, anchor=east},
    milestone label text={#1\mbox{ }},
    group label node/.style={text width=6cm,align=right,font=\RaggedLeft, anchor=east}] 
    {2018-12-01}{2019-12-31}
    \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=shortname} \\
    \ganttmilestone[milestone/.append style={fill=gray!50}]{Proposal decision}{2018-11-30} \\ %0
    \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=red!90}]{Potential proposal amendments}{2018-12-10}{2018-12-21} \\ %1
    \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=red!90}]{Travel \& accommodation research}{2019-01-01}{2019-02-28} \\ %2
    \ganttmilestone[milestone/.append style={fill=gray!50}]{Travel \& accommodation booking deadline}{2019-02-28} \\ %3
    \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=orange!90}]{Background theory reading}{2019-03-01}{2019-06-30} \\ %4
    \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=orange!90}]{Final admin (insurance, accounts etc.)}{2019-06-01}{2019-06-30} \\ %5     
    \ganttgroup[group/.append style={fill=blue!90}]{\textbf{IPP, Prague}}{2019-07-01}{2019-09-30} \\ %6
    \ganttmilestone[milestone/.append style={fill=gray!50}]{Sandpit event}{2019-09-01} \\ %7
    \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=OliveGreen}]{Writing project up}{2019-10-07}{2019-11-31} \\ %8
    \ganttlink{elem1}{elem2}    \ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
    \ganttlink{elem3}{elem4}    \ganttlink{elem4}{elem6}
    \ganttlink{elem5}{elem6}    \ganttlink{elem6}{elem8}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

As you can see it doesn't reproduce your chart exactly because there is so much stuff missing; but I hope the fix works for you?

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

Comment: I tried your fix, and have indicated in the code where I tried to implement it in case positioning of the command matters, but I didn't have any luck. I suspect it is because of compress calendar (which I hear has all sorts of issues) or because of how I am setting the nodes?

Comment: I tried the addition but it didn't work. I have since found Torborn's attempt worked so have gone with that. Thanks for your help. I also now know to be more specific and include packages etc when asking for help. Thanks